# For loop: replacement has one row more than data

Tags: r, for-loop

I am an beginner in R and have a problem. Any help would really be appreciated!
When I apply the for loop in the following (simplified) case, I get an error message saying "replacement has 5 rows, data has 4"

```
Country <- c("Germany", "France", "Italy", "Spain")
Unemploy <- c(2, 3, 4, 10)
Growth <- c(2, 7, 6, 9)
data <- data.frame(Country, Unemploy, Growth)

for (i in data$Country) {
     if (identical(data$Country[i], "France")) {
          data$Growth[i] <- "5"
     } else {
          data$Growth[i] <- "2"
     }
}
```

Following message given out:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Growth", value = c("2", "2", "2",  : 
replacement has 5 rows, data has 4
```

Comment: Sorry, should be "Growth"

Comment: Thanks TWL for correcting the mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ifelse` instead

```
data[ ,"Growth"] <- ifelse(data[ , "Country"] == "France", "5", "2")
```

Comment: For the OP: `Growth` was a `numeric` vector but now it is a `character` vector. If that was not your intent, use `5` and `2` (without the quotes) to remain numeric.

Comment: why mix `$` and `[` styles?

Comment: @flodel, now I used only one style. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
> for (i in data$Country){print(i)}
[1] "Germany"
[1] "France"
[1] "Italy"
[1] "Spain"
```

The `i in data$Country` syntax iterates through the values in that `data.frame` attribute. You are then using `i` as if it is a numerical index. So what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(data$Country)) {if (identical(data$Country[i],"France"))
+ {data$Growth[i]<-"5"}else{data$Growth[i]<-"2"}}
```

That being said the above is not idiomatic R, please see @Jilber's answer for a more idiomatic solution.

Comment: fwiw, you can do this "vectorized" using `ifelse`:  `data$Growth <- ifelse(data$Country == 'France', '5', '2')`

Comment: good point, i was just going to add something like that in :)

Comment: One thing, the first argument in the `identical` function is supplied as a factor, which will not work, I recommend using `identical(as.character(data$Country[i]), "France")`, or try `data$Country[i]=="France"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for (i in 1:length(data$Country)) {
    ...
```

Comment: Your answer does not add anything to the answers already there.

Comment: It's also incorrect.  Did you run it with the example data?  I'm guessing no